# Ant script for Adding different properties file based on environment(QC,STAGING,PRODUCTION)

Tags: java, ant

While making war file through ant script,how can we add properties file based on environment(QC,STAGING

Answer (score 0):

You can use a -Dstage=QC option on the command line and use ${stage} as the name of a properties file.

Comment: Can You explain little more about this.Should i have to place all these files at one particular location in SVN.

Comment: Well, that is completely up to sou. I do not know how you organize your build environment, your question is terse enough.